# RMS protected files SharePoint 2013 taking too long to OPEN or DOWNLOAD

Tags: sharepoint-server

In the SharePoint 2013 library we have enabled RMS protection.The RMS is working fine but the files take too long to open or even download. I have tried setting RMS on different site collections on different libraries but still the same issue. Rebooted the server, Restarted the SharePoint timer service but nothing seems to work. Initially the search was configured on the site and i was assuming,maybe that is the issue and I disabled the search and then tried.Still too much time to download.
Is it the normal behavior because when I upload the same file in a non RMS enabled library and try to open or download it, it takes fraction on seconds to open.

Kindly suggest something. Is it the normal behavior with RMS or something is wrong at the server level.
Thanks